Regression within each group
I am trying to run regression within each group and year. Here is what I have done:
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Year": [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
    "Group": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    "Value 1": [40, 20, 30, 45, 22, 34, 11, 88],
    "Value 2": [3, 22, 11, 55, 5, 9, 4, 15],
})

def func(group, var):
    X = group[var]  # independent variable
    y = group["Value 2"]  # dependent variable
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    group["Residual"] = sm.OLS(y, X, missing="drop").fit().resid
    return group

data.groupby(["Year", "Group"], group_keys=False).apply(func, var="Value 1")

It works just fine. However, my real dataset is huge. Is there a way to run this more efficiently? For example, using matrix? Becuase I kept getting following error and it's pretty slow.

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.73 GiB for an array with shape (229, 3359769) and data type float64


Is this the problem? "Functions that mutate the passed object can produce unexpected behavior or errors and are not supported." Try returning Residual itself instead of adding it to group.

Otherwise, you might check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples for tips on how to let us reproduce the error ourselves, like generating a df from an RNG.

The error is simply because my data is too giant like 300,0000 rows. So I don't think I can create reproducible examples. The code above works fine. The question is how to run this exercise efficiently if the dataset is huge.

Have you tried the dask.dataframe? link @Derek

def func2(group, var):
    X = group[['const', var]]  # independent variable
    y = group["Value 2"]  # dependent variable
    # Explicitly setting hasconst=True will be a bit faster.
    return sm.OLS(y, X, hasconst=True).fit().resid

# Having the assignment at the end is more efficient than thousands of times.
data["Residual"] = (
    # Adding a constant once is more efficient...
    sm.add_constant(
        # Dropping NA Values once is more efficient...
        data.dropna(subset=["Value 1", "Value 2"])
    )
    .groupby(["Year", "Group"], group_keys=False)
    .apply(func2, var="Value 1")
)
data

Output:
   Year Group  ID  Value 1  Value 2      Residual
0  2000     A   1       40        3  2.042810e-14
1  2000     A   2       20       22  1.065814e-14
2  2000     B   3       30       11 -2.309264e-14
3  2000     B   5       45       55 -1.421085e-14
4  2001     A   2       22        5 -4.440892e-15
5  2001     A   1       34        9 -5.329071e-15
6  2001     B   2       11        4  0.000000e+00
7  2001     B   3       88       15  0.000000e+00

